# Given a surjection of rings with nilpotent kernel, the root of a polynomial lifts to a unique root.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $ \phi : R_1 \rightarrow R_2$ be a surjection of rings such that the kernel is nilpotent, let $f \in R_1[T]$ be such that its image under the map induced by $\phi, \ $ namely $g \in R_2[T], \ $  has a root, $\overline{\alpha}$, and $g'(\overline{\alpha}) \in R_2^\times$. I'm trying to show that there's a unique $\alpha \in R_1$ such that: $\phi(\alpha)=\overline\alpha \ $ and $ \ f(\alpha)=0.$

- *Uniqueness*

if $ \ \alpha, \beta \in R_1$ are such that $f(\alpha)=f(\beta)=0 \ $ and $ \ \phi(\alpha)=\phi(\beta)=\overline{\alpha},\ $ then $g$ has a double root at $\overline{\alpha}$, thus $g'(\overline{\alpha}) \notin R_2^\times \ \  \unicode{x21af}$.

- *Existence*

I was thinking that we should show that if there's a solution in $\frac{R_1}{(ker \phi)^k}, \ $ then it lifts to a solution in $\frac{R_1}{(ker \phi)^{k+1}},$ and since $$ \exists \ n \text{ with } (\ ker \ \phi \ )^n= (0), \text{ we would get a solution in } \frac{R_1}{(0)} \cong R_1 \text{ as requested}$$  but I've got no clue on how to prove the existence of a lift to $ \frac{R_1}{(ker \phi)^{k+1}}, \  $ any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, we can make an (unimportant) reduction to simplify things. Namely, with $R=R_1$, $I=\ker \phi$, we have a polynomial $f\in R[T]$ whose reduction $\bar f\in (R/I)[T]$ has a root $\bar \alpha$, with $\bar f'(\bar \alpha)$ invertible. The goal is to show that, given that $I$ is nilpotent, that $\bar \alpha$ has a unique lift to a root of $f$. If $I^n = 0$, we can consider the filtration $$R = R/I^n \to R/I^{n-1}\to \cdots \to R/I$$ so it suffices to consider the case where $n=2$, since this allows us to lift at each stage.

So suppose $I^2=0$ and $\bar f$ has root $\bar \alpha$ with $\bar f'(\bar \alpha)$ invertible. Let $\alpha_0$ be *any* lift of $\bar \alpha$; we want to find a unique $a\in I$ for which $f(\alpha_0+a) = 0$. Let $f(x) = a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0$. Since $a^2=0$, we see that for any $m$, we have $(\alpha_0+a)^m = \alpha_0^m + m\alpha_0^{m-1}a$, so in particular we have $f(\alpha_0+a) = f(\alpha_0)+f'(\alpha_0)a$. Since $\bar f'(\bar \alpha)$ is invertible in $R/I$, there is some $b\in R$ and $y\in I$ for which $f'(\alpha_0)b = 1+y$. But then $f'(\alpha_0)$ is invertible in $R$, since $$f'(\alpha_0)b\cdot (1-y) = 1-y^2 = 1.$$ In particular we are forced to choose $a = -f(\alpha_0)f'(\alpha_0)^{-1}$, giving both existence and uniqueness of a lift.

This strategy allows you to even lift a root of $R/I$ uniquely to the $I$-adic completion of $R$, which, in fancier terms, is saying that for any ring $R$ and ideal $I$, the pair $(\hat R_I,I)$ is a henselian pair. This, sometimes in more or less general forms, is called "Hensel's lemma." Your particular question is simply a special case, where $\hat R_I = R$ since $I$ is nilpotent.

Comment: +1! p.s. it might be worth pointing out that OP's "uniqueness" argument is not correct: for instance, if $R_1=\mathbb{Z}\big/12\mathbb{Z}$, and $R_2=\mathbb{Z}\big/6\mathbb{Z}$, and $f=t^2-8t$, then $f$ has both $\overline{2}$ and $\overline{8}$ (resp $\overline{0}$ and $\overline{6}$) as roots, which have the same image in $R_2$, but $g$ has only a single root at $\overline{2}$ (resp $\overline{0}$) in $R_2$, not a double root.

Comment: g’(2) = 2 which is not invertible, so it’s not actual counterexample, OP’s proof seems elegant and correct to me! Thanks OP!

Comment: @Alessandro right, but the attempted proof that you give of uniqueness never uses the full strength of the hypothesis $g'(\overline{\alpha})\in R_2^\times$; if you reread your proof, you'll find that you only ever use $g'(\overline{\alpha})\neq 0$. my example is not meant to be a counterexample to the theorem – which vijay has given a nice proof of – but only to your attempted proof of uniqueness, which fails in the example I've given

Comment: (in particular, in your argument, you say that, if $\alpha\neq\beta\in R_1$ both map to $\overline{\alpha}$ under $\phi$, and are both roots of $f$ in $R_1[t]$, then $g$ has a double root at $\overline{\alpha}$, but this assertion is not true, as the example above shows. does that make sense?)